# Is there a script in google sheets that can pull data into one sheet from another sheet based on the google sheet link ID and tab name?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hi i am wondering if there is a google sheets script that can pull data into one sheet from another sheet based on the google sheet link ID and tab name. For example, I would like to have one file that has a column where i can enter a links (google sheet ID) and tab name and in the next column it will pull what is input in a specific tab and cell value into the sheet with the link ID.

Or open to some other solution to summarize over 50 separate files data, data is in template so i will need to pull the same cell on all tabs and files, but from all the different tabs. file contain separate tab for each week and separate file for each person.

thank you so much for any help in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

Mmm, I'm not sure if that's exactly what you need, but you have IMPORTRANGE that imports values from other spreadsheets based on ID or link, and tabName!Range

For example:

```
=IMPORTRANGE(A1,B1&"!"&C1)
```

[image]

See [documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en), for more infor: